# How to run JDK 8 Java web application in JDK 11?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have built a web application in JDK 8. Now I want to run that application in JDK 11. So is it possible to run a JDK 8 web application in JDK 11?

In my application, I have used servlets and JSP and database connectivity with MySQL.

Comment: @ayorgo That question has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible to run a JDK 8 web application in JDK 11?

For a normal application, the answer is simply yes.

For a web application, you don't run the app directly on a JDK or JRE.  You actually run it in a web container that runs on the JDK or JRE.  For example Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish and so on.  (For a webapp that uses just servlets and JDBC, you don't need a full J2EE container.)

However different webcontainers have different functionality and different ways of doing things that *may* be an impediment to a specific webapp.

So my advice is to find out what web containers are *recommended* for the webapp you are trying to run, and use one of those.  Choose a version of the container that that is advertised as supporting Java 11.

Comment: I was running that application in the Tomcat web server.

Comment: So my recommendation is to continue running it in a version of Tomcat that supports Java 11; see http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.